# boost::lambda::var nested in boost::bind not equivalent to boost::lambda::var by itself

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, c++03

I'm having a little trouble identifying some simple boost::lambda usage issues. I can make a simple lambda function like this:

```
int i = 0;
boost::lambda::var(i) = boost::lambda::_3; // Set 'i' to the 3rd parameter.
```

But as soon as I wrap that lambda function in a bind:

```
int i = 0;
boost::bind(boost::lambda::var(i) = boost::lambda::_3);  // Set 'i' to the 3rd parameter.
```

It becomes unusable:

```
(boost::lambda::var(i) = boost::lambda::_3)(0,1,2); // Compiles & behaves as expected. i == 2
boost::bind(boost::lambda::var(i) = boost::lambda::_3)(0, 1, 2); // Compile error
```

Does boost::lambda::var indeed produce a bindable function? Have I fudged the syntax somehow? It always tends to be something simple, any light you could shed is appreciated :)

(compiled with MSVC2008 & boost v1.50)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to prevent substitution

- [Preventing argument substitution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#idp153492360)

In this case `boost::lambda::protect` seems in order

Also, check the relation of Boost Bind with Boost Lambda:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lambda/s08.html#idp153645176

> The Boost Bind [bind] library has partially overlapping functionality with the BLL. Basically, the Boost Bind library (BB in the sequel) implements the bind expression part of BLL. There are, however, some semantical differerences.
>
> The BLL and BB evolved separately, and have different implementations. This means that **the bind expressions from the BB cannot be used within bind expressions, or within other type of lambda expressions, of the BLL**. The same holds for using BLL bind expressions in the BB. The libraries can coexist, however, as the names of the BB library are in boost namespace, whereas the BLL names are in boost::lambda namespace.

And more information on that page

Comment: Your comment about bind vs lamba::bind checks out - using the correct library helped a little bit.

However, lambda::protect helps in the scenario:
`boost::lambda::bind(boost::lambda::var(i) = boost::lambda::_3, 0, 1, 2)();` , but not the scenario I asked about (in which the parameters are provided outside the lambda::bind):
`boost::lambda::bind(boost::lambda::var(i) = boost::lambda::_3)(0, 1, 2);`